# Why do some TBBs in a Template in TemplateBuilder show up as TCM IDs, not names?

Tags: 2011, cme, template-builder

We've noticed that in a new Tridion CM environment some TBBs in a template are not showing up normally with the name, rather a TCM ID with a weird icon as in the screen snippet below:

[image]

What does this mean?

Answer (score 9):

The reason this occurs is because the user running Template Builder does not have read permissions to the folder that this TBB is in.  The TBB runs in Template Builder, but none of the metadata about the TBB is available due to the permissions setting.

Comment: Indeed - this is the standard behaviour in any list in Tridion. Showing you the title of the item wouldn't be in keeping with you not having read permission. On the other hand, it would be misleading to indicate that the item didn't exist. Say for example that the list is of the items that are preventing you from deleting something. Knowing at least the ID of the item gives you the possibility of asking an admin to help.